# Anonymous Component in vue Route

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I want to use vue-router to switch between two tabs of a side navigation (general and account), but i get `<Anonymous Component>` displayed in vue devtools and i don't know what i'm doing wrong.

```
// app.js
import routes from "./routes";
Vue.use(VueRouter);

import General from './components/settings/General';
Vue.component('General', General);
import Account from './components/settings/Account';
Vue.component('Account', Account);

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router: new VueRouter({
        mode: 'history',
        routes: routes
    }),
    ...
});
```

The `routes.js` that I use in the Vue instance:

```
const components = {
    General: require("./components/settings/General"),
    Account: require("./components/settings/Account")
}
const vueRoutes = require("../../vue-routes.json");
function assignComponents(routes) {
    return routes.map(route => {
        route.component = components[route.component]
        return route;
    })
}
const assignedRoutes = assignComponents(vueRoutes);
export default assignedRoutes;
```

The routes are defined in a .json file `vue-routes.json` in the root of my project:

```
[
    {
        "path": "/settings/general",
        "component": "General"
    }, {
        "path": "/settings/account",
        "component": "Account"
    }
]
```

In my Settings component i have:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <router-link to="/settings/general">
            General
        </router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
        <router-link to="/settings/account">
            Account
        </router-link>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <keep-alive>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </keep-alive>
</div>
...
import General from "./General";
import Account from "./Account";
...
components: {General, Account},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `require` is obsolete and  shouldn't generally be used without a reason, it can generally be replaced with spec-compatible `import`. In case of the router it specifically allows for lazy-loaded components provided as asynchronous components. In this case `default` import doesn't need to be specified because module object is handled by the framework:

```
const components = {
    General: () => import("./components/settings/General"),
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the `.default` option to each component in `routes.js` and it worked

```
const components = {
    General: require("./components/settings/General").default,
    Account: require("./components/settings/Account").default
}
const vueRoutes = require("../../vue-routes.json");
function assignComponents(routes) {
    return routes.map(route => {
        route.component = components[route.component]
        return route;
    })
}
const assignedRoutes = assignComponents(vueRoutes);
export default assignedRoutes;
```